# Selenium - Removing and Appending class Values

Tags: python, html, selenium, class, tags

Part of my program needs to toggle which element gets the `class` value `"selected"`.

```
<div class="countryValues">
        <div data-val="" >USA and Canada</div>
        <div data-val="US" >USA - All</div>
        <div data-val="US-AL" >USA - Alabama</div>
        <div data-val="US-AK" class="selected">USA - Alaska</div>
</div>
```

Clicking any one of the given sub-elements in `"countryValues"` will remove the `class` entirely from every other `div`, and then insert `class="selected"` into the clicked one.

The code I've written thus far:

```
# locales looks like this: ['US-AL', 'US-AK', 'US-AZ', ...]

# Clear all of the "selected" class values.
for loc_option in locales:
    option_n = with_browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-val='" + loc_option + "']")
    option_n_class = option_n.get_attribute("class")
    if option_n_class == "selected":
        # Do something to remove the class.
# Put the "selected" class value in where loc fits.
loc_to_select = with_browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-val='" + loc + "']")
loc_to_select.click()
```

The first error occurs, however, on the line `option_n = with_browser.find_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-val='" + loc_option + "']"))`:

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string

`locales` is a list of `data-val` values, as strings, and both `loc` and `loc_options` pick an item from it

I've tried various routes to selecting the elements by `data-val` and have consulted the documentation, but none have worked out.

Is there a more straightforward way to remove the `"selected"` value from one and add it to another?

For example, my goal is to get from this:

```
<div class="countryValues">
        <div data-val="" >USA and Canada</div>
        <div data-val="US" >USA - All</div>
        <div data-val="US-AL" >USA - Alabama</div>
        <div data-val="US-AK" class="selected">USA - Alaska</div>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="countryValues">
        <div data-val="" >USA and Canada</div>
        <div data-val="US" >USA - All</div>
        <div data-val="US-AL" class="selected">USA - Alabama</div>
        <div data-val="US-AK">USA - Alaska</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add `locales` to the code?

Comment: Try with `loc_to_select = with_browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[data-val='" + loc + "']")`

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I added a description of ```locales``` to the code.

Comment: "Is there a way I can remove the 'selected' value from one and add it to another?" Yes, by clicking the item you want to select.

Comment: Click adds `selected` class to the element and removes from another, as you said. Is your goal do it without click? What is your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an error because of double `()`:

```
option_n = with_browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-val='" + loc_option + "']")
```

Comment: That did repair the error. Double ```()``` are needed in ```expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".css-element"))```, for example, hence my error.